# Error Deploying .NET 6 Web API with GitHub Actions and Azure CLI: "not enough values to unpack"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, github-actions, .net-6.0

I am trying to deploying the .NET 6 Web Api using GitHub actions. The error message is as follows:

[image]

This is my GitHub action:

```
name: Build ASP.NET code (Web App for WebAPI)

on:
  
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
       environment:
        description: 'Environment'
        type: environment
        required: true
       app-configuration:
        type: choice
        description: Select App Settings File
        default: 'appsettings.Development.json'
        options:
        - appsettings.Development.json
        - appsettings.SIT.json
        required: true


env:
      AZURE_WEBAPP_WEBAPI_NAME: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_WEBAPI_NAME }}
      CERT: ${{ secrets.CERT }}
      WORKING_DIRECTORY: src/Test.WebApi
      BUILD_CONFIGURATION:  ${{ inputs.build-configuration }}
      #NUGET_VERSION: 4.4.1
      CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_ID }}
      TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.TENANT_ID }}
      RESOURCE_GROUP: ${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP }}
      JSON_PATH: ${{ inputs.app-configuration }}

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Navigate to Workspace
        run: cd ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}

      - name: Create Build Directory
        run: mkdir _build
        
      - name: Build Project
        run: dotnet build ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}/Test.WebApi.sln --property:OutputPath="../_build" --configuration Release

      - name: Test Project
        run:  dotnet test ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}/Test.WebApi.Tests --no-restore --verbosity normal

      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1.0.0
        with:
          name:  ASP-app
          path: "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}/_build"  
  
  deploy-to-staging-slot:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Logs in with below Azure credentials
      - name: login to az
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "$CERT" > sfh-mvc-cert.pem
          az login --service-principal -u $CLIENT_ID -p sfh-mvc-cert.pem --tenant $TENANT_ID
          
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: ASP-app
          path: download/ASP-app
  
      - name: test
        run: |
          cd download/ASP-app
          echo "listing ASP-app"
          ls

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2.2.9
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_WEBAPI_NAME }}
          package: download/ASP-app
          slot-name: staging
      
      - name: Deafult WebApp Configuration from appsettings.json
        uses: azure/CLI@v1
        with:
           azcliversion: 2.42.0
           inlineScript: |
              az webapp config appsettings set -g "${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP }}" -n '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_WEBAPI_NAME }}' --settings "@Test.WebApi/Test.WebApi/appsettings.json" -s staging
        
      - name: WebApp Configuration
        uses: azure/CLI@v1
        with:
           azcliversion: 2.42.0
           inlineScript: |
              az webapp config appsettings set -g "${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP }}" -n '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_WEBAPI_NAME }}' --settings "@Test.WebApi/Test.WebApi/${{ env.JSON_PATH }}" -s staging
  
  deploy-to-production-slot:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: deploy-to-staging-slot
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }} 
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: login to az
      shell: bash
      run: |
          echo "$CERT" > sfh-mvc-cert.pem
          az login --service-principal -u $CLIENT_ID -p sfh-mvc-cert.pem --tenant $TENANT_ID
          
    - name: 'Swap Slots: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_WEBAPI_NAME }}'
      uses: Azure/cli@v1.0.0
      with:
        inlineScript: az webapp deployment slot swap --resource-group ${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP }} --name ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_WEBAPI_NAME }} --slot staging --target-slot production

    - name: Deafult WebApp Configuration from appsettings.json
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
          azcliversion: 2.42.0
          inlineScript: |
            az webapp config appsettings set -g "${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP }}" -n '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_WEBAPI_NAME }}' --settings "@Test.WebApi/Test.WebApi/appsettings.json"

    - name: WebApp Configuration
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.42.0
        inlineScript: |
              az webapp config appsettings set -g ${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP }} -n '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_WEBAPI_NAME }}' --settings "@Test.WebApi/Test.WebApi/${{ env.JSON_PATH }}"
```

This is my appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "ServiceBusConfigOption": {
    "ConnectionString": "KeyVaultSecret-ServiceBusConnectionString",
    "TopicsEmailTemplate": "EmailTemplates",
    "TopicUserSetting": "UserSettings"
  },

  "JwtConfigOption": {
    "Secret": "KeyVaultSecret-ApiJwtSecret",
    "Issuer": "KeyVaultSecret-ApiJwtIssuer",
    "Audience": "KeyVaultSecret-ApiJwtAudience",
    "ClientId": "KeyVaultSecret-ApiJwtClientId",
    "ClientSecret": "KeyVaultSecret-ApiJwtClientSecret",
    "ExpiryMinutes": 20
  },

  "StorageConfigOption": {
    "ConnectionString": "KeyVaultSecret-AzureWebJobStorage"
  },

  "RepositoryOptions": {
    "CosmosConnectionString": "KeyVaultSecret-ConnectionString",
    "DatabaseId": "TestDb",
    "OptimizeBandwidth": true,
    "ContainerPerItemType": true,
    "AllowBulkExecution": true,
    "SerializationOptions": {
      "IgnoreNullValues": true,
      "PropertyNamingPolicy": "Default"
    }
  },

  "KeyVaultConfigOption": {
    "Url": "{keyvaultUrl}.vault.azure.net",
    "RefreshIntervalInMinutes": 45,
    "SecretPrefix": "KeyVaultSecret"
  }
}
```

Please let me know if required any additional information.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please verify if file path after `--settings` i.e. `@Test.WebApi/Test.WebApi/appsettings.json` path is correct and that it is a valid JSON. Apparently, JSON parsing is failing. Not related to GHA but your own code and/or its related configuration. Try to run the same sequence of commands from your local terminal and you'll figure it out.

Comment: Thank You. You're absolutely right! It was issue with the settings json path.